# Form onsubmit="return validate()" issue

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am new to this site, and I wasn't able to find an answer *(I honestly gave it my best shot)*.

I have a form that I would like to validate before it completes its action. My knowledge of PHP is very limited, so hopefully you can help me figure out a JavaScript solution.

Here is an example of what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
// FAIL IF NOT A NUMBER
function validate()
    {
    if (a.value == isNaN)
    {
    return false;
    }
    if (b.value == isNaN)
    {
    return false;
    }
    if (c.value == isNaN)
    {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
</script>

<form name="form1" action="#" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post">
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">
<input type="text" name="c">
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specifically is going wrong with what you have right now?

Comment: I'm not getting the alert when I test for a false return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try @Scott

```
function validate() {
    a = document.getElementsByName("a")[0].value;
    b = document.getElementsByName("b")[0].value;
    c = document.getElementsByName("c")[0].value;

    if (isNaN(a[0].value) && a!="") {
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(a[0].value) && b!="") {
        return false;
    }

    if (isNaN(a[0].value) && c!="") {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

<form name="form1" action="" onsubmit="validate()" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <input type="text" name="b">
    <input type="text" name="c">
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried it out, but I think there is bigger issue. I'm getting a _"is not defined"_ error for a, b, and c. - I've run into and fixed this problem many times but my memory seems to be somewhere else.

I added **var a = document.getElementsByName("a");** , which stopped the error but when I test if the form return is true by using **console.log("sent");**, nothing appears.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working :( ... it's very strange, for some reason I feel like the mistake is a simple one. I've gone as far as declaring a charset lol.

Comment: It doesn't return anything right now, it might be cancelling out on the return function... I just made a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/3mGjx/

Comment: We weren't using proper isNaN syntax properly, I've updated again.

Comment: WORKS! Well done! --- for some reason I can't upvote your post _because I'm new_; others should do so if possible!

Comment: Alright that's been solved; however, I just realized I need to be able to put "." in the input boxes too, because I'm working with currency.

Comment: You're the best, thanks a ton for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I'd refrain from allowing currency symbols, you could have the currency preceding the input box. You could then use the HTML5 placeholder and output something like "$ amount". These are just a few ideas for you to think over.

Comment: Basically I will use this to input currency without the "$" sign, but I know I have a habit of typing the "$" which could hurt my MySQL database that it will link to. I also need to be able to use decimals, forgot all about those haha

Comment: I think you'll be needing RegExp in that case - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp.

Comment: Awesome, I just made something that allows all chars but the "$" sign: http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/wScKq/

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function in the button

```
<button onclick="validate()" type="submit">Submit</button>
<input type="text" id="a" name="a">
```

and catch the value like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// FAIL IF NOT A NUMBER
function validate()
    {
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value; // or getElementByName
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = document.getElementById("d").value;
    if (a.match(/[a-zA-Z]))
    {
    return false;
    }
    if (b.value == isNaN)
    {
    return false;
    }
    if (c.value == isNaN)
    {
    return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. Just to make sure I added an alert before the **return false;** , it didn't give me the alert when I typed in letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML CODE : 

<!-- createNewAbout is my module name and submitAboutContent is the Controller You you can call it the backend function . 
You Can Use URL in Form Action too.  -->
    <form action="createNewAbout/submitAboutContent" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validationOnlySubmitForm('submitStaffData', new Array('subject','details'))">
<!--  I am Calling a function before submit if this function returns true then only the data will be Submit . -->
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
<!--   there are simple form -->
    <label for="title">Enter Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title" id="subject" name="subject">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="title">Enter Description</label>
    <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description" id="details" name="details"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label for="title">Add Image</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" style="padding: 5px;font-size: 15px;width: 100px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 mrg15px ">
    <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </form>


<!-- this is the function Which i am Calling . I am taking value of  name attribute of button to disable button for multiple fuction call and also taking an array of values of name attribute of  manditory fields. Here we cant use values of ID attribute so we have to use name . -->
    <script> 
    function validationOnlySubmitForm(button_name="", arr="") {
    var fields = arr, flag  = 0;
    document.getElementsByName(button_name)[0].setAttribute("disabled" , true);
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= fields.length - 1 ; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByName(fields[i])[0].value.length == 0) {
    flag = 1;
    document.getElementsByName(fields[i])[0].focus();
    alert(fields[i] + " is manditory.");
    document.getElementsByName(button_name)[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
    return false;
    }
    }

    if (flag == 0)
    return true;
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, please can you add some text to explain your code? It would also be nice to format your code for quality as well. Thanks!

Comment: In which line you getting problem please explain , I will describe that portion for you . Thanks.